# c++ condition variable wait that returns class member

Tags: c++, lambda, condition-variable

I'm new to Lambdas and trying to get a std::condition_variable to wait on an atomic bool that is a member of the same class from another class function that references it. So essentially,

```
class A{

public:
static std::atomic<bool> processed;
static std::condition_variable cvar_processed;
}
```

---

```
    class B{

    Type somefunction(T1 arg1 , T2 arg2){

      A obja;

      {
       std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk1(processed_mutex);
       std::cout<< "somefunction is waiting..." std::endl;
       obja.cvar_processed.wait(lk1, [] { return obja.processed.load(); });
       lk1.unlock();
      }
// Continue with cool stuff


    return type;
   }

 }
```

---

I can't seem to access obja.processed.load() inside the lambda expression. I've tried capturing "this" like [this] - but I think I'm doing something wrong with the syntax that does not immediately stand out to me.

Comment: `obja.cvar_processed.wait(lk1, [&obja] { return obja.processed.load(); });`

Comment: And - in general - the bool you use to signal with doesn't need to be an atomic (as all uses of it should be under the mutex). Also your unlock is superflouous.

Comment: You trying to use `obja` inside lambda, why are you capturing `this`?

Comment: Its atomic because it is part of a multi threaded application.

Comment: Why are `processed` and `cvar_processed` declared as `static` but being accessing via an object? That implies they shouldn't be `static` to begin with